# how to connect to metamask with react native

Tags: react-native, blockchain

I want to connect to metamask with react native.
I searched on google and I am using react-native-walletconnect
But I got an error.
Somebody helps me.
I tried to use useWalletConnect from react-native-walletconnect

Comment: hello provide proper error message

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.